.desktop file not launching on double click
I'm having trouble getting my .desktop application to launch with a double click. I've created a .desktop file that runs a .bash script, and I've given all necessary permissions to both the .desktop and .bash files. However, it doesn't work when I double click the .desktop file.
Ubuntu version : 22.04
Interestingly, if I use the following command, the application launches correctly:
gio launch ~/Desktop/gui_app.desktop

Here are the details of my files:
.bash file (/home/dragon/gui.bash):
#!/bin/bash

# Source ROS 2 environment
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash

# Launch the first ROS 2 launch file
ros2 run py_testing_pkg gui_original

.desktop file (~/Desktop/gui_app.desktop):
[Desktop Entry]
Name=my_gui
Version=1.0
Comment=Run my ROS2 Node
Icon=/home/dragon/Pictures/gui.png
Exec=/home/dragon/gui.bash
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26

I've ensured that both files are executable with chmod +x.
Does anyone have any idea why double-clicking the .desktop file doesn't launch the application, while using gio launch works perfectly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I bet ros2 isn't in PATH when the script is run through the .desktop file. Try and replace ros2 with the full path to the script / executable (you can find out the full path by running type ros2 in a terminal)

Try using: Exec=bash -c '/home/dragon/gui.bash'

@kos @kos i followed your advice but still my .desktop application doesn't work on double click.
/opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2 run py_testing_pkg gui_original

@JayCravens I tried the comment Exec=bash -c "/home/dragon/gui.bash" but still i'm having same issues.

I still think it's related to the environment, are you setting up some sort of environment for ros2 to work? If you are and you're doing so in ~/.bashrc, you should set up the same environment in the .desktop file. If you're not, please comment out the whole script and just leave env > /home/dragon/env in it, then check the output of colordiff <(env | sort) <(sort /home/dragon/env) if you're willing to install colordiff, otherwise just diff <(env | sort) <(sort /home/dragon/env). It should highlight any difference in the environment.

@kos it was sourcing issue. Thank you for your inputs

source ros2_ws into .bash file
#!/bin/bash

# Source ROS 2 environment
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source ~/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash

# Launch the first ROS 2 launch file
ros2 run py_testing_pkg gui_original

